# Why am I not getting any leading zeros when using md5 hashing algorithm?

Tags: python, hash, while-loop, md5, leading-zero

I am building a simple example to demonstrate what the process is for a bitcoin miner. I am trying to replicate the example where a combination of hashed inputs and a random string gives you more leading zeros than the previous hash solved the problem.

The issue is, I never get any leading zero's after hundreds of thousands of iterations

I have tried a while loop with 3 inputs and an i+=1 iteration which will break when there are 2 leading zeros

```
import hashlib
import random

def miningExample(previousHash,numTx):
    # The hash generated from the previous block forms the basis of the new block header
    previousHash = previousHash

    # Create an array to contain the transactions
    transactions = []
    hashTransactions = []
    # Randomly generate numTx transactions each comprising x BTC
    for Tx in range(numTx):
        # Simulate payments in the network
        transactions.append(random.randint(1,100))
        print("Transaction {} of {} BTC".format(Tx,transactions[Tx]))

        # Hash each transaction
        blockstring = "{}".format(transactions[Tx])
        hashTransactions.append(hashlib.sha256(blockstring.encode()).hexdigest())
        print(hashTransactions[Tx],"\n")

    # Concatenate each string together
    hashString = " "

    for element in hashTransactions:
        hashString += str(element)

    print("The hash string is",hashString)

    # Now it is time to solve the hashing algorithm by adding a random number to the string and hashing
    # First, calculate how many "leading zeros" are in the previous hash
    leadingZeros = len(previousHash) - len(previousHash.lstrip('0'))
    print("The mining difficulty is",leadingZeros)

    # Iteratively increase the "nonce" or "random string" by 1 until we find a new hash with 14 leading zeros
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        nonce = hashString + str(i)
        hashAttempt = hashlib.md5(nonce.encode()).hexdigest()
        print("The iteration number is", i, '\n', "The new hash string is", hashAttempt)

        # If the hashAttempt has more leading zeros, the algorithm has been solved
        if len(previousHash) - len(previousHash.lstrip('0')) > leadingZeros:
            blockHeader = hashAttempt
            print("It took {} attempts to solve the algorithm".format(i),"The new block header is",hashAttempt)
            break

miningExample("01adf44c7d69767585",3)
```

I am expecting to get 2 leading zeros after only a few hundred iterations. Am I approaching this in the correct way?

Edit: Break function was referencing the wrong variable

Comment: Did you do the math? Assuming a uniform hash, what is the probability of having 8 leading 0-bits (= 2 hex characters)?

Comment: I did not calculate the probability, could you guide me to an article?

Comment: The math is simply, for every additional leading zero hex digit the probability goes down by a factor of 16. So you'd expect to see one leading zero after 16 iterations, two after 256 iterations, 3 after 4096 iterations, 4 after 65536 iterations, and so on. Of course this is a random variable with a non-zero variance.

Comment: Which makes me curious as to why I can run millions of iterations and not find a solution

Comment: I have found my mistake, my break condition was aligned to the wrong variable